# 22.04 waking up from sleep issues on Malibal Aon

Tags: 22.04, suspend, power-management

I have a malibal aon s1. It is a pretty nice lightweight laptop, however I am running into issues with sleep. I am so confused on why the laptop will go to sleep but won't wake up, this was working fine until a few weeks. To get my laptop awake, I put power down the latop, and boot up again, which sucks to do everytime my laptop sleeps.

I have `journalctl | grep power` nothing special except telling me it is sleeping, `journalctl | grep wakeup` has nothing in it. I read the `journalctl -b` logs, and there was nothing in there too. I am so frustrated that this won't wake up from sleep.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I have also have my sleep state set to deep, and it causes issues still. I have logs that my laptop would wakeup from sleep, but now it doesn't, anything I can try helps!